# Can Scala REPL on SBT call people's own scripts? (Like OptiML?)

Tags: scala

I know `sbt console` will open an interactive Scala REPL and load in all the library dependencies so people can test Scala code right there. However, I wonder if there's anyway to use and treat in a way so that people can interact with my programs directly, instead of interacting with libraries.

For example, if I write a `Vector` class, how can someone call it from `sbt console` or any other Scala REPL interface??

Think of it as that you are trying to write a Scala library but you want to provide a simple REPL interface for people to interact with it, like R, instead of asking people to add the library as dependency.

The effect is similar as described here: http://stanford-ppl.github.io/Delite/optiml/getting_started.html

Comment: Do you mean like `load` in the REPL ? See the `REPL`section in http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/

Comment: @ccheneson `load` can only interpret a file from top to bottom which is for example a problem when there is a reference to a definition that is defined later. It's for one file, but I'm writing more like a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

You can use initialCommands key in sbt to do this

So in build.sbt if you put

```
initialCommands in console := """import my.project._
val myObj = MyObject("Hello", "World")
    """
```

after you type 'console', you can start using myObj or the classes in my.project

[http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/scala.html#initial](http://SBT%20Docs%20Link)

Comment: This is perhaps the most direct answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Emmm..do you know if I can override Scala REPL's help message as well? initialCommands are executed before REPL's help message comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you cannot use modified code without reloading the REPL. Just run:

```
sbt "~ ; console"
```

And then import your classes with `import your.package._` and use them from there.

If you make any changes to your library code, just hit `CTRL+D` or `:quit` and it will detect file changes, compile them and enter the REPL again. You can then use the history (navigating with the arrows up/down) to execute anything from the previous session again.